# Wrap_content displays text when layout_weight="0" but replacing wrap with dp values is causing content to disappear. Why?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Code with dp values-

```
<TextView
    android:text="VIP List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
/>
```

Putting dp values for width and height causes the text to go off the screen. This textview has the least weight among the 4 textviews i am using.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because wrap_content tells the `TextView` to measure its content.

In any case you should never use a weight of 0. If you want the view not to take any space use `android:visible="gone"` instead.